# Notify user about bounced confirmation emails

Tags: django

My website requires users to confirm their email address they used during their registration. Therefore I send the usual confirmation email. If such a email bounces I am notified by my email provider (sendgrid).
I would like to notify a user when he comes the next time to my website about the problem with his email.
The notification from my email provider is an asynchron callback to some URL and I would need a way to to find the session of the user and store the information.

When sending the email I could add some identifier to the request, which sendgrid would then include into the bounce message. However for some reasons I would prefer not to go this way, if possible. I would prefer to store the email address the user used in his anonymous session and use this information to later lookup his session.

Is this somewhow possible? Can I add some information to an anonymous session and is this saved in the DB so I can later look it up? My Session config is the default Django configuration?

Comment: Do you have to do it that way or you are open to other suggestions?

Comment: I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: I am under the assumption that every user gets a unique email send their way, so all it boils down is to extract information of which user's email got bounced. Can you share details of how emails are sent etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [Django sessions system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/). It is enabled by default in Django projects created with `manage.py startproject`.

Basically, the `SessionMiddleware` adds a `session` attribute to all requests performed to your Django project. You can use this attribute as a standard python dict in your views:

```
def my_view(request):

    # At some point, you retrieved the visitor email...
    user_email = 'john@example.com'
    request.session['user_email'] = user_email
```

Information stored in this dict are persistant by default.

Technically, the data stored in this dict are stored in your default DB, in table `django_session`. A unique `session_key` is associated with those data, and this key is stored on your visitor computer in a cookie. This means the data has an expiration date. When the user come back to your website, if the cookie is still present (and not outdated), you can retrieve the information in `request.session` as you stored it some days before.

[Django sessions persistency behavior can be controlled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) with 2 settings:

- [SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE)

False by default. If set to true, sessions are destroyed when the user close his browser. You probably want to keep this value set to False.

- [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)

This is the default duration of sessions, in seconds. Default is 1209600 corresponding to 2 weeks.

Note: you can modify the session duration by directly calling `request.session.set_expiry()`. This allows to override the default settings on a per-session basis.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'm not so sure that its a great idea to rely on being able to identify returning anonymous sessions.

Another way to handle this issue that I've seen farely often is to allow the user to complete their registration, and be able to log in with their username and password, but mark the user as unverified, perhaps with a field on a [user profile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).  Unverified users can simply be denied access to the bulk of your site.  And after logging in they can request to have their verification email sent again if they haven't yet received it, as well as having the option to update their email if they made a mistake.

It looks like the [django-registration](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration) app helps with a lot of this.

Docs: https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/install.html

Comment: I am using django-registration and users can already request a new confirmation email through entering their email address. But ideally I would be able to present them a note that their last email did get bounce when they come back to my site.

Answer (score 0):

Tobitobs, as another way: you can attach anonymous email to his localStorage bucket, and later you can get this back. But I user clears cookies and another data in browser - these emails cloud be lost.

One more way - to save emails with a snapshot of device - browser-device-os-IP (or something) and store this info at DB.